# How to keep line breaks when using .text() method for jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve a typewriting effect and my content consists of a lot of HTML entities. The problem with using .html() is that since it writes out each letter at a time, it will type out `&` then `l` then `t` then `;` and finally it would change to `<`.

**HTML**

```
<p id="src">
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;!--[if lt IE 7]&gt;      &lt;html class=&quot;no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7&quot;&gt; &lt;![endif]--&gt;
&lt;!--[if IE 7]&gt;         &lt;html class=&quot;no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8&quot;&gt; &lt;![endif]--&gt;
&lt;!--[if IE 8]&gt;         &lt;html class=&quot;no-js lt-ie9&quot;&gt; &lt;![endif]--&gt;
&lt;!--[if lt IE 9]&gt;      &lt;html class=&quot;no-js lt-ie9&quot;&gt; &lt;![endif]--&gt;
</p>
<p id="typed-paragraph">
    <span id="target"></span>
    <span id="typed-cursor">|</span>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
#src {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
(function(){
    var srcText = $("#src").html();
        i = 0;
        result = srcText[i];
    setInterval(function() {
        if(i == srcText.length-1) {
            clearInterval(this);
            return;
        };
        i++;
        result += srcText[i].replace("\n", "<br />");
        $("#target").html(result);
    }, 150); // the period between every character and next one, in milliseonds.
})();
```

You can see the example of it here
http://jsfiddle.net/j9KF5/9/

But if I use .text() then I lose all the line breaks.

Ultimately, how I can either fix the entities problem or the line break problem?

Comment: Try unescape() javascript function to the html that you are trying to render on-the-fly such a way that your html char codes are replaced with proper tags before you start printing it.

Comment: @DhanasekarSM that's really not helpful.

Comment: Please include a complete example in the question itself, not just a link. _"To be clear, links to jsfiddle and similar services are OK but a question or answer should stand on its own. Enough information should be included in any post to still make it useful for future visitors even if all the links were to break, in other words."_ http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151616/133242

Comment: FWIW, I kind of like this "multi-line string" approach: http://jsfiddle.net/j9KF5/13/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the HTML entities nor any complex string replacing.

All you need is a little CSS:

```
#target {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

and use the `.text()` approach:

```
(function(){
    var srcText = $("#src").text().trim();
        i = 0;
        result = srcText[i];
    setInterval(function() {
        if(i == srcText.length-1) {
            clearInterval(this);
            return;
        };
        i++;
        result += srcText[i];
        $("#target").text(result);

    }, 150); // the period between every character and next one, in milliseonds.
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/vsb9F/

Comment: That's what `.text()` does.

Comment: No... I already said, it's `.text()`, nothing more. Read some docs, perhaps?

Comment: So simple! The .text() just prints out the text, .trim() removes white space around the text, and css white-space property wraps the text when there's a line break. WOW and I had thought about using  the white-space property but on #src, not #target (GAH). Thanks!

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you!

Comment: Another alternative is `whitespace: pre-wrap`, which avoids long lines making the box wider

Comment: For my case I had to use white-space: pre-line; to prevent some display glitches but the white-space css attribute was indeed the solution.

Answer (score 18):

To anyone who's looking for what the title of the question actually asks (this is how I got to this page, "how to keep line breaks when using jQuery's text() method"), you can use something like this:

```
(function($){
   $.fn.innerText = function(msg) {
         if (msg) {
            if (document.body.innerText) {
               for (var i in this) {
                  this[i].innerText = msg;
               }
            } else {
               for (var i in this) {
                  this[i].innerHTML.replace(/&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;/gi,"n").replace(/(&amp;lt;([^&amp;gt;]+)&amp;gt;)/gi, "");
               }
            }
            return this;
         } else {
            if (document.body.innerText) {
               return this[0].innerText;
            } else {
               return this[0].innerHTML.replace(/&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;/gi,"n").replace(/(&amp;lt;([^&amp;gt;]+)&amp;gt;)/gi, "");
            }
         }
   };
})(jQuery);
```

Now call $('.some-class').innerText() to get the text with line breaks preserved.

Comment: Nice one but the accepted answer also works =] I don't know how come that `white-space: pre;` CSS rule actually affects how jQuery gets its `text()` but it does work.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using `.innerText` rather than implementing a complex loop in the other answers, since it saves you so much more time. To do so, simply do `$(selector)[0].innerText`.

Here's a demo. Begin typing into the input. Make sure to add new lines and see how `innerText` preserves them!

```js
var jquerytext = $('.jQuerytext');
var innerText = $('.innerText');
$('.text').on('input', function(){
  jquerytext.text($(this).text());
  innerText[0].innerText=($(this)[0].innerText);
})
```

```css
pre{
  display:inline;
}
.text{
  border:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">Hello World!
Begin typing in here, and make sure to press Enter to make new lines!
</div>
<h2>jQuery <pre>.text()</pre></h2>
<div class="jQuerytext">
Begin typing in here, and make sure to press Enter to make new lines!
</div>
<h2>Vanilla <pre>.innerText</pre></h2>
<div class="innerText">
Begin typing in here, and make sure to press Enter to make new lines!
</div>
```

Comment: ... this should be a top answer for this question

Comment: When you want to save newlines form a contenteditable div with jquery, this is your recipe.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `.replace` on the `srcText` variable.

```
srcText = srcText.replace(/&lt;/g, "<"); //performs this with global modifier to cover whole string
```

Placing a series of `.replace` calls inside a function, with each call modified to a different character would sanitise the whole string before you print it to the screen.

Comment: What about all the other HTML entities, or escapes like `&#9731;`? This is not a viable general solution.

Comment: agreed, though in the scope of this specific question, there are only three characters types to replace.