# Why does text() remove new line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery. I have a div like this

```
<div id="test">
    <c:out value="${data.content }" />
</div>
```

The c:out value is "Test1 \n Test2\n Test3". It renders with new line correctly on the page. Then I need to get the content in div 'test' in javascript. Code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($("#test").text());
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        alert($("#test").text());
    }
}
```

Alert box displays a result like "111234567891011 Test1 Test2 Test3". It removes the new lines and adds a "header". Is there anyway to prevent jquery to remove the new line characters in text()? Why there is the header added in the text value? Thanks

Comment: Provide rendered HTML markup as it appears in browser

Comment: Try `.html()` instead of `.text()` and see what the log says.

Comment: *"It renders with new line correctly on the page."* That sounds something magically converts your `\n` to `<br>` elements and thus the line breaks are gone. If the line breaks were preserved, you would not see them, because in HTML line breaks are treated as spaces. So, `.text()` doesn't remove the line breaks, they are never there.

Comment: Could be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678446/how-to-keep-line-breaks-when-using-text-method-for-jquery

Comment: Thanks for all the comment. I found the reason. It's not about jquery. The div is inside a container which has complicated client side rendering logic. The strange result is from that logic.