# Save line-breaks in a custom Electron text editor

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, fs

I'm trying to create a text editor in electron. I have this in my HTML file:

```html
<pre><div class="file-content" contenteditable="true"></div></pre>
<button onclick="saveFile();">Save</button>
```

In a Javascript file, I have this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const $ = require('jquery');

function saveFile() {
    fs.writeFile([filepath], $('.file-content').text(), function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
    });
}
```

But when I enter a text with a few lines in it, when I click the save button, the text gets written as one line. For example:

Input:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

File after save:

```
line1line2line3
```

Comment: Have you determined if it's the `text()` call that's removing the newlines, or if it's the `writeFile` call that's doing it?

Comment: [docs](https://api.jquery.com/text/) say "Due to variations in the HTML parsers in different browsers, the text returned may vary in newlines and other white space"

Comment: @3174N I've checked the ['duplicate'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678446/how-to-keep-line-breaks-when-using-text-method-for-jquery) and none of the answers on that page work for your scenario.  The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22678568/4166522) does .text() on a prefilled <p> tag, which is exactly what you're already doing.  That works for a prefilled <p> tag, but not for your scenario of a content editable <div> where you've typed in the text. The 'whitespace: pre' in that answer refers to the the target when writing the result to the screen so also doesn't help us.

Comment: The regex substitution in the [other upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27079244/4166522) also doesn't correctly work with a content-editable div output.  It's replacing <br> tags with linebreaks (\n) and Chromium is putting <div> tags in your entered text, not <br>.

Comment: I had written an answer to your question, which I can't now post.  However it was based on [this code in Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/nathansmith/86b5d4b23ed968a92fd4#file-2-converttotext-js) which broadly DOES do what you want.  In fact all you need are a couple of lines from it.

Comment: You need to start with the html, since .text() is stripping out the line breaks.  So `let value = $('.file-content').html();`.  Now use the lines `value = value.replace(/<div>/gi, '\n');` and `value = value.replace(/<(.*?)>/g, '');` from the Gist.  Then write `value` to your file. I've tested this in Electron with your input and it works.

Comment: Doing it this way does break the rule of [never using regexes to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), of course, so there may be better answers.

Comment: @RichN [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27079244/13368737) did resolve my question, so I marked the question as duplicate. But your answer also works for me, so I'm thankful to you for answering it.